# Do logic is wrong

Tags: vba

Can anyone see the problem in this logic?

I seem to be stuck in an infinite loop where the code just goes to the next page even if it finds the right acqCode.

```
 flagFound = 0

 Do 
        If StrComp(temp1, acqCode) = 0 then 
            Print #iOutFileNum, "It's 1st!!!! :)" 
            flagFound = 1
        Elseif StrComp(temp2, acqCode) = 0 then
            Print #iOutFileNum, "It's 2nd!!!! :)" 
            flagFound = 1
        Elseif StrComp(temp3, acqCode) = 0 then
            Print #iOutFileNum, "It's 3rd!!!! :)" 
            flagFound = 1
        Elseif StrComp(temp4, acqCode) = 0 then
            Print #iOutFileNum, "It's 4th!!!! :)"
            flagFound = 1
        Elseif StrComp(temp5, acqCode) = 0 then
            Print #iOutFileNum, "It's 5th!!!! :)"
            flagFound = 1
        Elseif StrComp(temp6, acqCode) = 0 then
            Print #iOutFileNum, "It's 6th!!!! :)"
            flagFound = 1
        Else
            If flagFound = 0 then 
                'go to next page
            End If
        End If
    Loop Until flagFound = 1'to end Do While
```

Comment: Are any of your compares true on the first pass? What is the value of flagFound entering this loop?

Comment: on the first pass no, but on the second run the first If will be triggered. The value of flagFound entering the loop is 0.

Comment: Well it will go to the next page on the first pass then. If all the comparisons fail it will drop into your else where you check if `flagFound = 0` which it does

Comment: Any chance you're facing some trailing or leading spaces? How are your temp* vars reset between pages? Can you post more of the code around this block? Might help...

Comment: @tom502: Yes but why does it go to the next page more then once (it actually continuously goes to the next page)

Comment: Because it doesn't break your loop - flagFound still doesn't equal 1 ... ahh but then the 2nd time it will - I'm up to speed

Comment: @David: no I checked (good old print statement)

Comment: @Tom: why not? if any of the If's occur then flagFound is equal 1.

Comment: could you replace the flagFound=1 with an `Exit Do` ?

Comment: To reiterate David's second question, how are temp1 through temp6 reset when going to the next page?

Comment: @psubsee2003: why would I reset them? When flagFound 0 then loop. When it's 1 stop looping.

Comment: @SeanCheshire: I tried that first and now again. Didn't work :(

Comment: Reset may be a bad choice of words, but if either temp* or acqCode do not change between loops, how will they ever return true?

Comment: When do you get the data for the 1st page? I see the `'go to next page`, but no `'read the first page`

Comment: @Sean: When the Do starts it's already on the first page.

Comment: @psubsee2003: acqCode stays the same and that is what I am looking for. temp* changes.

Comment: @PaulKar. I figured that was the case, but I think the point that Sean, David, I are all trying to make are *how* are you setting temp1, temp2, temp3, etc?  Are you pulling them from each page when you move to the next page?

Comment: You've put a breakpoint and debugged this, right?

Comment: Try adding "exit do" as a line after each successful evaluation. I'm nearly 100% sure you aren't getting successful "=1" evaluations on the strcomp and thus are creating an infinite loop.

Comment: @enderland: StrComp function returns 0 if the two strings are equal.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I don't think the problem is there since I use print statements and see what temp* is. It prints "It's 1st" and then continues to loop.

Comment: @Paul We're just trying to find out how temp* are being initialized/reset during each iteration/page advance. What does "go to Next Page" mean literally? If going to the "next page" never happens, how can this code ever escape the loop to accomplish the change that will cause the proper value to be found? I don't mean to seem dense, but I just don't think I can see enough here to really know what's going on.

Comment: Make sure you have deleted all contents of whatever file you are writing each time before running so you don't just read the previous "match" and get stuck in an infinite loop later, but not ever print to the file again (if you are doing `open iOutFileNum for append` this is nearly assuredly your problem).

Comment: Which application are you in?

Comment: ditto what David just said.... but to answer your original question.. the logic looks fine, so the only conclusion I can draw is that the comparisons are never true, which means `temp*` never is the same as acqCode.

Answer (score 1):

checking the logic, I can find nothing wrong. I would look at the results of `strcomp`.

`strcomp("A ","A")` returns 1, even though the strings will look the same on the screen. Perhaps a `trim()` would help.

unless you have a need to compare in a non-case sensitive way (eg `"ABC" = "abc"`) then a straight string comparison may be more readable. The `if..elseif..else` construct can also be rewritten as a `select case`

```
flagFound = 0
Do
    Select Case acqcode
        Case temp1
            Debug.Print "It's 1st!!!! :)"
            flagFound = 1
        Case temp2
            Debug.Print "It's 2nd!!!! :)"
            flagFound = 1
        Case temp3
            Debug.Print "It's 3rd!!!! :)"
            flagFound = 1
        Case temp4
            Debug.Print "It's 4th!!!! :)"
            flagFound = 1
        Case temp5
            Debug.Print "It's 5th!!!! :)"
            flagFound = 1
        Case temp6
            Debug.Print "It's 6th!!!! :)"
            flagFound = 1
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "next page"
    End Select
Loop Until flagFound = 1 'to end Do While
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also checked your logic with my own fake data (I used Excel for my test, but if you are using another application, the basics are still the same).

I was able to get the loop to terminate in any page I wanted in any of the 6 conditions using your exact logic.  So that means your general logic is sound.

As you have not shown how your `temp*` variables are populated or shown the source data, the most likely conclusion I can come to is you have no valid conditions.

There is only one other possibility that has been ignored because of your statement you have an infinite loop. Is it possible that your loop is not actually infinite (if it were you would run out of pages or get an overflow or our of memory error)?  If the loop is not infinite, then it could mean that the problem could be in your `Print` statement.  Try replacing them with Debug.Print and do not write to an external file.  If it runs correctly, then that could be your problem.  If it still behaves the same, then it means that your problem has to be the fact that your String comparison is never true.

However, if it locks up or appears to be in an infinite loop, it is possible your file in your `Print` statement is trying to write too was never opened.  You don't show it, but I believe you need to do the following before trying to write to a file using the `Print` statement:

```
fileNum = FreeFile ' next file number
Open file For Append As #fileNum  'or Output instead of append for a new file 
                                  ' (overwriting existing file)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
flagFound = 0

Do 
    If StrComp(temp1, acqCode) = 0 then 
        Print #iOutFileNum, "It's 1st!!!! :)" 
        flagFound = 1
    Elseif StrComp(temp2, acqCode) = 0 then
        Print #iOutFileNum, "It's 2nd!!!! :)" 
        flagFound = 1
    Elseif StrComp(temp3, acqCode) = 0 then
        Print #iOutFileNum, "It's 3rd!!!! :)" 
        flagFound = 1
    Elseif StrComp(temp4, acqCode) = 0 then
        Print #iOutFileNum, "It's 4th!!!! :)"
        flagFound = 1
    Elseif StrComp(temp5, acqCode) = 0 then
        Print #iOutFileNum, "It's 5th!!!! :)"
        flagFound = 1
    Elseif StrComp(temp6, acqCode) = 0 then
        Print #iOutFileNum, "It's 6th!!!! :)"
        flagFound = 1
    End If

       If flagFound = 0 then 
            'go to next page
       End If

Loop Until flagFound = 1'to end Do While
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer.  It looks like all you did was move the comment over which has no effect in VBA.  Can you explain the change a little better?